# LinqPad - Share data between queries

Tags: linqpad

I have two connections to two distinct servers.
I'd like to access data from databases on both servers. It seems impossible (or at least complicated).

I was thinking it may be easier to do some requests on one server, store the results in memory in some variable and then access that variable in another query on the other server.

I tried with static variables in `MyExtensions` as well as with 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("myVariable", results)` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("myVariable")` but both don't work.

Comment: Are the database structures the same on both servers? If so you can create a second connection using `var dc2 = new UserQuery( new SqlConnection(connectionString));`

Comment: Databases are on different servers (one Azure one hosted with another provider).

Comment: If the database structures are exactly the same, then being on two servers should not matter.

Comment: These are different, non-related, with-different schemas, databases on different, non-related, servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but the solution ended up being much simple than I had expected.

Since I had a project with both of datacontexts (on different servers) I wished to query, I added a  reference (F4 in a query, then Additional References->Find your bin folder or whatever) to the .dll of my project.  I added  a config/connectionstrings section to the app.config of the query that contained the names of the connectionStrings my project context was looking for with the correct connection Info.

This gave me not only access to my data context, but also much of the business logic (for instance, repos/dtos/viewModels/other transformations) from my project.  From there, I could grab whatever I needed from DB/server A, put it my preferred data type (usually a List), and then have it interact with data from DB/server B as needed.

Hope this helps!